# MVC4 Forms Authentication not timing out

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

I am using the MVC4 Simple Membership Provider. Initially the website logins were timing out prematurely and the user was requested to log back in. After searching, it seemed the solution was to add a "machineKey" element so that if the app pool was recycled, the login token would still be recognized. After adding that element to web.config, now my website is not timing out at all. Any ideas what might be going on?

```
<machineKey validationKey="D2BCD45AADBB49F1CB3537A1FEA07F93BDFA78A863849E3CC76CDFFAD183FE81BB709EACA8BF3E28BCCE0A5D58A147F4EA68B93B3C9768CA085867D613D14B5C,IsolateApps"
            decryptionKey="DD27E5C7B983D2DDDE6371A08F4AEE9A2ECC754593FB4E33,IsolateApps" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="60" protection="All" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: Odd, when I hand edited the web.config to timeout=2 or timeout=5, that works. But when I published with timeout=60, and then even restarted the website, it was not timing out even after several hours. Strange how something so simple in concept acts so mysterious in practice...

Comment: Then, after hand editing to 60 minutes, I had to log back on after 57 minutes since the last login and page display. Gues I'm going to do a binary search here to see when it is timing out. Dang...

Comment: Well, now seems to be working and all I did each time was edit web.config setting the timeout. A login was not required after 58 minutes, but was after 61 minutes. Dazed and confused...